# PHP crop image in shape other than square like oval shape or round

Tags: php, image, image-processing, gd, crop

I want to crop images in PHP. Cropping in rectangular shape is all common and easy to do.
Can you guide me that how i can crop image in shape other than square like in oval or round shape. 
[image: Cropped]

[image: Original Image]

Comment: dude, its not the 80's anymore.

Comment: You should look into anti-aliasing and images with opacity (such as PNG). I'm not aware of any PHP libraries that can do image cutting on an arbitrary path (as per your example) but it should be possible. Maybe look at the code in `GIMP` to see whether you could use any of that?

Comment: @Dagon - true. [Neither is it the 1980s or the '80s](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Apostrophes)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually do that with `ImageMagick` ... See [Crop or mask an image into a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999251/crop-or-mask-an-image-into-a-circle) and [Crop image into circle and add border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223437/crop-image-into-circle-and-add-border) for good examples

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answer, you can even blur the border with Image Magick's vignette effect, look for vignetteImage method.