# Cut out an arbitrary piece of an image and save it

Tags: javascript, php, image-processing

I'm searching for a way to cut out any shape from an image and save it somewhere on the server.
I'm looking for solutions in PHP and/or JavaScript but haven't found anything yet.

I'm not sure but as far as I know the gd-library in PHP is only capable of cutting out or copying rectangular shapes from source images.
In JavaScript this probably can be achieved somehow through the canvas-object but I haven't found any libraries that provide such a function (rafael.js or paper.js don't seem to do the job) ...

Example:

Let's say i got the following image:
[image]

Now I would like to mark a certain part of that image (by x/y-coordinates):
[image]

And finally i want to extract that part as a single image (with the rest of the background beeing filled black):
[image]

Thank you for any help

Comment: You will need [`GD-library`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Images are just a matrix of pixels. Php gives you access to each individual pixel with `imagecolorat`. Your task involves choosing which pixels to copy, and saving them into a new image. As all image files are rectangular, you must also choose a background color for pixels outside the shape, eg white or transparent. This is all possible with `GD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PHP only, [imagecopy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php) lets you easily copy a part of an image by coordinates and do with it as you wish.

Edit: Using [Imagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) it's possible to crop images to specific shapes among other functions.

Comment: According to the doc you linked in your comment, imagecopy only supports rectangular shapes for copying (start coordinates (x and y) and scale (width and height))

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10071441/2931464 I haven't tried this suite too much myself, but it has very in-depth image manipulation capabilities like its morphology and transforming modules. It might be what you're looking for.

Comment: the actual accepted answer is the comment about imagick. Thanks for that.