# Create a circle thumbnail from jpeg in PHP

Tags: php

Hi currently I built have function to create a thumbnail from an image and it does so, however I want it to be a circle thumbnail not a rectangle, how can I achieve this without using any external libraries just php built in methods? thank you

```
 function createThumb( $imagepath, $thumbFile, $thumbWidth )
{
// load image and get image size
  $img = imagecreatefromjpeg( "$imagepath" );
  $width = imagesx( $img );
  $height = imagesy( $img );  
  // calculate thumbnail size
  $new_width = $thumbWidth;
  $new_height = floor( $height * ( $thumbWidth / $width ) );
  // create a new temporary image
  $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );
  // copy and resize old image into new image
  imagecopyresized( $tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );
  // save thumbnail into a file in the temp directory below script or somewhere
  imagejpeg( $tmp_img, $thumbFile );
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679238/circular-thumbnail-with-php

Comment: Try this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagearc.php

Comment: also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223437/crop-image-into-circle-and-add-border have you actually searched anything?

Comment: @Jorg yes, however I didnt find any solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS is a better way to do it actually .

```
.class-name {
   border-radius : 30px;
}
```

Comment: Actually CSS is not the answer for every problem. Somebody might need circular images, i.e. to send them to a mobile app